# Recommend a Distro for 504Mb RAM, 2GB HDD

Tags: system-installation, distro-recommendation

I have an ASUS EEE PC 2G Surf netbook, Celeron M CPU 800MHz, 504 MB RAM, 2 GB TIF card as drive E and 2 GB soldered HDD. I have Win XP OS installed.

Unfortunately, due to recent security updates, it now has only 224 KB of free space left on the HDD. I'd like to install a minimal OS on this; so, I can use the netbook to stream music only. Will delete Win XP and replace with linux.

I am completely new to linux/; so, I have no idea where to start. Is there a small enough version of Ubuntu that I can use on this netbook, and how do I download and install it?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you intend to remove WinXP?

Comment: Do you have 2 GB RAM as your title states or 504 MB RAM as mentioned in the text? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/955867/edit) and correct!

Answer (score 1):

Both [Xubuntu](https://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/) and my personal favorite [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net) are very lightweight, I run them successfully on hardware with lower specs. Find installation instructions on the linked websites.

About Lubuntu, the [wiki.ubuntu.com](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu) says:

> We have done many tests and we've found out that Lubuntu can be installed on a Pentium II or Celeron system with 128 MB of RAM, but such a system would not perform well enough for daily use.
>   With 256MB - 384MB of RAM, the performance will be better and the system will be more usable.
>   With 512MB of RAM, you don't need to worry much.
>
> [H]ere are the minimum supported requirements of Lubuntu: 266 MHz processor; 128 MB; 3 GB hard drive; no fancy graphics
>
> A more usable system would have: 512 MHz processor or faster, 32 or 64 bits;
>   512 MB of RAM;
>   6 GB hard drive;
>   no fancy graphics